# Searching value in list for Value map

Tags: qfield

I am using Value maps in QGIS and QField.

I use Value Maps with long lists (+500 diff values) all the time, but it is tedious to scroll through the list if I need a value from the bottom of the list.

Is there a way to type (e.g. first letters of the value I'm looking for) so sort off filter in my value-map list?

I know it is possible, because I have done it once before.

I especially want this for Qfield, but if I know how to do it in QGIS, it is no problem transfering this setup to QField.

Small example of 'my' value map list (in reality +500) values:
I will often need to select 'watermelon' but since it is on the bottom of my list, I always have to scroll down a lot.

[Apple

Banana

Cucumber

Eggplant

Fruit

Grapefruit

... - Hundreds of other values - ...

Watermelon]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use value relation with types and subtypes. This is a kind of filter and it limits the choice of values.
See https://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/qgis-3-2-drive-down-lists-aka-value-relation-widget

An autocomplete function would be nice but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Since 1.8 - Selma auto completion is supported in relation reference and value relation widgets.

Comment: When auto-complete is enabled, you can easily perform a search in all available parent features.
With space-separated input, you can search for the beginning of multiple words in the display name of the parent features.